# What are required parameters for an ICE candidate?

Tags: java, webrtc, sdp, candidate, ice4j

If I call toString() from a org.ice4j.ice.LocalCandidate object then I receive an output like:

```
candidate:1 1 udp 2130706431 192.168.233.1 10000 typ host
```

The candidate which I receive form a browser look different:

```
2791736470 1 udp 2122063615 192.168.233.1 59763 typ host generation 0 ufrag 8pZ1 network-id 1
```

We see additional values for `generation`, `ufrag` and `network-id`. Must I set this values or is this only a nice to have? If I must set it, where can I find the values for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`generation`, `ufrag` and `network-id` are non-standard extensions used by Google's libwebrtc (see [RFC 5245](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245#section-15.1) for the standard ones which may be followed by additional key-value pairs) which is used by Chrome and Safari.
They can be ignored, other browsers like Firefox don't emit them either.